# How will these 3 very similar strings sound different when tuned to low C on a baritone ukulele?

Tags: strings, ukulele

I prefer to use a nylon core, wound strig for the low C on my baritone ukulele.  I had trouble finding just the right thing, and the closest I found at my local shop was a set of classical guitar strings, D'Addario EJ45.  In the pack, only three strings are wound (for the low end of the guitar).  Their specs reads:

> D(4th) .029 in. 15.62 lb. tension
> A(5th) .035 in. 15.89 lb. tension
> E(6th) .043 in. 14.19 lb. tension

Of these, the desired pitch (C) is in between the D and A.  My scale length is approx. 19 inches, and the package says that "25.5 in scale length is used for tension measurements."

I'm wondering, which of these three strings should I use, and also what would be the difference between the various choices.

Comment: Have you searched online to see what the specs of a pack of baritone ukulele strings is? Also have you tried a string tension calculator to see which string will best match the intended tension for your uke: https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/guitar-string-tension

Comment: Can your shop not order uke strings? I do my share of "off-label" stringing, using harp strings on my baroque violin, but uke strings are pretty easy to get, and then you wouldn't have to throw two of them away.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the thicker string will have:

1- More stable tuning when plucked- the string will not go as sharp when plucked hard.

2- More stable tuning when fretting hard or "bending"- a greater tension increase is required to change the pitch, because of the square root relationship between tension and pitch.  It will also require more force from your fingers to cause this tension increase.

3- A darker or duller tone- because of increased damping of higher frequencies

4- A slightly less pure tone- inharmonicity increases with increased thickness

Plus the obvious: 5- Heavier strings feel different, since they require more force to fret and don't move as easily when plucked.

The correct thickness depends on which factors you value more in a string.

Importantly, though, the tension measurements you gave are for strings tuned to guitar pitches on a guitar-scale instrument.  If you are targeting a certain tension, you will need to recalculate the tensions for your ukulele pitch on your ukulele-scale instrument.

As a quick estimate, we can say that 19" scale is very nearly the 5th fret of a guitar, so a string tuned to C on your ukulele will be at the same tension as that same string tuned to G (5 semitones lower) on a guitar.  This means that the 0.043 E string would be pretty tight on the uke (+3 semitones), the 0.035 A would be pretty loose (-2 semitones), and the 0.029 D would be very loose (-7 semitones).  If you like the tension of this set on a guitar, you need roughly a 0.038 or 0.040 string with the same construction.  If that is not available, you can try the 0.035 "A" string, but you may find it too loose.

Answer (score 0):

From a physics standpoint,  each of those strings has a different mass/length as well as a different coefficient of elasticity.  Each will thus have a different decay profile and a different harmonics amplitude profile.

There's also a possible consideration of the tension required to tune to the desired note. Will that warp the uke?